# How show database in activity?

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I'm create an app which contain three activity and database and two table , first table fixed in listview , but how set second table in activity showdb, when click item listview show detaile itme in showdb activity

for example | first table ID (1,2,3) , nameitem(US,AU,IQ).

second table ID (1,2,3) , infoNI(US : detaile ..., AU : detaile ..., IQ : detaile ...).

when click US , in showdb activity show info US , how do that ?!!!

### SQLiteOpenHelper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.dbtest/databases/";
public static String DB_NAME = "ex4.sqlite"; 
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

public static final String TB_USER = "Users";

private SQLiteDatabase myDB;
private Context context;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);  
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public synchronized void close(){
    if(myDB!=null){
        myDB.close();
    }
    super.close();
}

public List<String> getAllUsers(){
    List<String> listUsers = new ArrayList<String>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c;

    try {
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TB_USER , null);
        if(c == null) return null;

        String name;
        c.moveToFirst();
        do {            
            name = c.getString(1);          
            listUsers.add(name);
        } while (c.moveToNext()); 
        c.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99", e.getMessage());
    }


    db.close();     

    return listUsers;
}



public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}


public void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    try {
        InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        String outputFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outputFileName);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;

        while((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - copyDatabase", e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();      

    if (dbExist) {

    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tle99 - create", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}


private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase tempDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        tempDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        Log.e("tle99 - check", e.getMessage());
    }
    if (tempDB != null)
        tempDB.close();
    return tempDB != null ? true : false;
}}
```

### MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

DatabaseHelper dbHeplper;
ListView lvUsers;
ListAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbHeplper = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    try {
        dbHeplper.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    lvUsers = (ListView)findViewById(id.lvUsers);
    List<String> listUsers = dbHeplper.getAllUsers();

    if(listUsers != null){
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),
                R.layout.row,R.id.textView1,
                listUsers);
        lvUsers.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    lvUsers.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position,long id) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, showdb.class);
                intent.putExtra("position",position);    
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}}
```

### showdbActivity

activity three showdb (in this activity , show data which in file database).

```
public class showdbActivity extends Activity {

TextView tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_showdb);

tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
tv2= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.detaile);

 }}
```

Comment: Welcome to the Stack Exchange network.
Unfortunately, your question is vague and unclear.

Please clarify your specific problem. As it’s currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. 

Be sure to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: sorry for my written , my english language is not good ^_^ , my problem is , i want show my databse in activity when click listview item

Comment: What do you mean show your database? please change the mysql tag to sqlite

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```
lvUsers.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position,long id) {
             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, showdbActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("position",listUsers.get(position));    
                startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

into your DBActivity.java , in onCreate()

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String user = intent.getStringExtra("position");
    if(user!=null){
        // fetch the corresponding deatils of user from database                
    }
```